# Kendo Hierarchical Datasource for treeview, filter to checked nodes

Tags: datasource, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am using the Kendo Hierarchical Datasource for a Kendo UI Treeview.
On a click event, I want to leave only the checked roms in the datasource.

I tried

```
    $('#treeview')
         .getKendoTreeView()
         .dataSource
         .filter({ 
                  field: "checked", 
                  operator: "eq", 
                  value: true });
```

But to no avail.

Do I have the correct field?

Also, for bonus points, how do I remove the filter?

Comment: What is `getKendoTreeView()`? I cannot find it in the documentation. Shouldn't it be  `$('#treeview').data("kendoTreeView").dataSource.filter(....)`

Comment: When I run them, I get the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`checked` is the correct field if you have defined it as so in the template :

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    checkboxes: { template: "<input type='checkbox' name='checkedNodes' #= item.isChecked ? 'checked' : '' # value='#= item.id #' />" },
    dataSource: [{ 
        id: 1, text: "My Documents", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "rootfolder", items: [
            { id: 2, text: "about.html", expanded: true, isChecked: false, spriteCssClass: "folder" },
            { id: 3, text: "index.html", expanded: true, isChecked: true, spriteCssClass: "folder" }
        ]
     }]
});
```

in my case, it is named `isChecked` (see `item.isChecked` in my code).

But, in order to filter correctly, be careful : `filter` only acts on the current level (see for example this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303235/kendoui-filter-treeview)).

And for your bonus question, to remove the filter, simply apply the following code :

```
$('#treeview')
     .data("kendoTreeView")
     .dataSource
     .filter({ });
```

(same as before on all levels on your hierarchy!).

---

**Edit**

Here is some fiddle in order to play with the filter : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/RHh67/ .