# Kendo HierarchicalDataSource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have created a kendo HierarchicalDataSource

```
var fontidatasource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
data: vm.get("Source")
});
```

I want search in it the item that are checked.

I have tried to use a gatherStates function (kendo documentation), but don't function...

Comment: But... how do you _check_ items in a `HierarchicalDataSource`? Do you mean a `kendoTreeView` that (of course) uses as data source a `HierarchicalDataSource`?

Comment: In my HierarchicalDataSource there is a voice checked: true or false
   {checked:true}
No i want to see the checked item without the kendotreeview, in kendo treeview i know how do it.

Comment: Is that checked part of HierarchicalDataSource? I cannot see any documentation on that. Or do you mean that is a field that you defined on each node of the tree?

Comment: Yes is a field defined on each node.
{ id:.... checke:true, items: [{ id:... checked:false},{id... checked:true}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that there is not such filtering option for HierarchicalDataSources.

You might try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12475871/1802671) even that it says TreeView it applies here since the data model is the same.

Comment: There is a way to make a loop to iterate through the HierarchicalDataSources?

Comment: If you don't mind too much about memory: write your own recursive function?

Comment: I try to write it but it tell error.. if you want to help me.

Comment: I would need to know more exactly what should be the output of the function, the id, the elements without items, a reference to found elements...

Comment: Json example:
 [{ id: "id", checked: true, items: [{ id: "id", checked: true, items:[]}, {id: "id", checked: true, items:[]}] }]

I want to do an action when an element have cheched:true
The tree can have more level...

Comment: I want to create a function that search in the hierarchical json object all the element that have checked:true and put the element in an array.

Comment: You still did not define how does the output look like and what about if one node says `checked: false` if it should stop the search. If the output is a tree, I expect so.

Comment: No in the function if the checked:true  i want to doing a push in an array. if it false nothing.  and there is no output because i want to do the cicle for fill an array.

Comment: FUNCTION
CICLE
   if(el.checked) { push({el}); } else {}
END CICLE
END FUNCTION